# Log4net just stopped working, got a reason why, but don't know how to fix it

Tags: c#, log4net

My log4net used to work, and not sure exactly when it stopped working, but today when I put the application onto a production server, I noticed no logs getting produced, here is the reason why, does anyone know how to fix this?

```
log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821]. Loaded from [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices\5da47f19\dc42c9c9\assembly\dl3\8f8d7275\00beb281_ec53c601\log4net.DLL]. (.NET Runtime [2.0.50727.4927] on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0)
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository for assembly [ISDS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [MyASM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices\5da47f19\dc42c9c9\assembly\dl3\38092252\c8d83679_5e56ca01\ISDS.DLL]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [MyASM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] **does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified**.
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [MyASM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
```

Comment: What's the param value you passed in for the log name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason this happens is when the loading order of assemblies changes, and you have a log reference before your log4net configuration.

Where is log4net configured in your application?  If it's programmatically, trace it and ensure that log4net is being configured before your first call to `GetLogger`.  I tend to throw a log reference just after I configure log4net, to ensure this.

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
log = LogManager.GetLogger(...));
```

Comment: I forgot to include the global.asax file , where these methods used to reside....